# Как выбрать уникальные строки из текстого файла

Tags: php

Доброго вечера всем. Есть файл info.txt который содержит множество строк типа:

```
MACHINE1,user1,17.02.2018,12:44:34
MOSTERM004,user2,17.02.2018,13:53:20
MOSTERM001,user3,17.02.2018,14:07:40 
MAIN5,user1,17.02.2018,14:07:55 
MOSTERM001,user2,17.02.2018,15:04:17 
MAIN3,user2,17.02.2018,19:47:03
```

Это история тех, кто и когда заходил на какие компьютеры.

1. Как мне выбрать только уникальные строки основываясь на именах `userX` (мне нужен только один `user1, user2` и т.п.)
2. Как при этом выбрать последнюю дату каждого пользователя?
3. И для полноты картины хотелось бы сохранить отфильтрованные данные в этот же файл `info.txt` обратно.

И еще, я начал уже считывать через массив, по возможности, можно ли было бы  продолжить далее в таком виде. Спасибо.

```
$filename = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\logon\info.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
$content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
fclose($fp);
//print_r($lines);
//echo($lines[0]);
//echo($lines[1]);
```

Comment: Поясните пункт 3. Нужно в выходной файл записать все данные какие были, но с какой-то сортировкой или в файле оставить по одной записи для каждого пользователя?

Comment: Нужно оставить по одной строке для каждого пользователя, выбрав последнюю свежую дату и записать новое содержимое обратно в файл. То есть, у нас должно получиться: MAIN5,user1,17.02.2018,14:07:55 (след строка) MAIN3,user2,17.02.2018,19:47:03 (след строка) MOSTERM001,user3,17.02.2018,14:07:40 (не могу в комментарии указать новую строку)

Comment: то есть выбираем уникальных пользователей, но при этом последние (свежие) их даты захода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Сюда будем все складывать
$data = [];
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
while ($row = fgets($fp)) { // читаем файл построчно
  $rec = explode(',', $row);
  $user = $rec[1];
  // парсим дату и переводим в unix-time 
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i:s', $rec[2] . ' ' . $rec[3])->getTimestamp();
  // Если информации о таком пользователе нет или дата более старая
  if (!isset($data[$user]) || $data[$user]['date'] < $date) {
    // Добавляем информацию о пользователе
    $data[$user] = [
      // Указываем распарсенную дату
      'date' => $date,
      // и исходную строку
      'row' => $row
    ]
  }
}
fclose($fp);

// Перезаписываем файл
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
foreach ($data as $row)
  fwrite($row['row'] . PHP_EOL);
fclose($fp);
```

Если записи идут строго по возрастанию времени, то код можно упростить

```
// Сюда будем все складывать
$data = [];
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
while ($row = fgets($fp)) { // читаем файл построчно
  $rec = explode(',', $row);
  $user = $rec[1];
  // Добавляем или перезаписываем информацию о пользователе
  $data[$user] = $row;
}
fclose($fp);

// Перезаписываем файл
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
foreach ($data as $row)
  fwrite($row . PHP_EOL);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Записи идут по увеличению времени. Можно не заморачиваться проверкой по дате и сразу перезаписывать

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko С getTimestamp ошибся. Там вместо `.` нужно писать `->`. А с массивами, действительно, конструкция `$data =[]` появилась в 5.4. До этого нужно было писать `$data = array()`

Comment: @rjhdby Добавил и второй вариант

Comment: ), а я удалил свой комментарий потому что смотрю - нет того знака уже, подумал может мне показалось).

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов:

```
$filename = 'info.txt';
$data = [];
// Прочитать файл, сохраняя в массив уникальных юзеров
array_map(function($i) use(&$data) {
    $user = str_getcsv($i);
    $data[$user[1]] = join(',', $user);
}, file($filename));
// Перезаписать файл 'info.txt'
file_put_contents($filename, join(PHP_EOL, array_values($data)));
```

Результат:

```
MAIN5,user1,17.02.2018,14:07:55 
MAIN3,user2,17.02.2018,19:47:03
MOSTERM001,user3,17.02.2018,14:07:40
```

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko первый вариант принадлежит не мне, но на первый взгляд его ещё нужно допиливать, и похоже что человек его писал "на коленке", т.к. такой конкатенации `$rec[2] + ' ' + $rec[3]` в PHP нет.  "_Установить седьмую не проблема. Вопрос, нужно?_" нужно )

Comment: да, хорошо, ok:)

Comment: первый вариант мне нравится, но он что-то не работает. ругается на строку где 'row' = $row, что Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']' И странно там похоже нужен такой же знак => (присвоение элемента массиву), а не "=".

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko Эдуард прав. Писалось на коленке. Но сейчас, вроде, все подчистил